# Arguments in super

Tags: java, constructor, super

Tell me please, what cannot be passed in arguments to method super ? why this code does not compile ?

```
class Base {
    static {
        System.out.println("Static");
    }
    public Base(String s) {
        System.out.println("Base " + s);
    }
}

class Sub extends Base {
    private final String Str = "Constructor";
    public Sub(Str) { // Error here
        super(Str);
        System.out.println("Sub " + Str);
    }
}


    public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base B = new Sub();
    }
}
```

I mean , why this code is work :

```
 class Sub extends Base {
    public static String Str = "Constructor";
    public Sub() {
        super(Str);
        System.out.println("Sub " + Str);
    }
}
```

If I change my arguments to static ?

Comment: `public Sub(String Str)` ? And  `Base B = new Sub();` is not valid since you don't have a no args constructor.

Comment: No, its Quiz. Its correct code. I dont understand why unswer is compilation error /

Comment: All constructors/functions arguments need to have a type associated with them...

Comment: If its a quiz probably wasn't meant to be throuwn into a compiler and asked about on so

Comment: Let get rid of the answers section altogether on `SO` :P

Comment: But why ? I dont understand this example /

Comment: as an argument to the constructor of the superclass can not pass non-static fields of the class, the result of a non-static method or this reference. Its answer I think

Comment: Please, let's stick to Java standards. Variables starts in lowercase letters. Let's not carry the Microsoft and Delphi coding standards to Java. I thank you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you use is slightly wrong.

`public Sub(Str)`

should be

`public Sub(SomeTypeHere Str)`

Answer (score 0):

It should either be

```
private final static String Str = "Constructor";
public Sub() { // Error here
    super(Str);
    System.out.println("Sub " + Str);
}
```

or

```
private final String Str = "Constructor";
public Sub(String mystring) { // Error here
    super(mystring);
    System.out.println("Sub " + Str);
}
```

Note that having:

```
private final String Str = "Constructor";
public Sub(String Str) { // Error here
    super(Str);
    System.out.println("Sub " + Str);
}
```

will hide your `private final String Str = "Constructor";` which is likely not what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

You want this

```
class Sub extends Base {
    private final String Str = "Constructor";
    public Sub(String Str) { // Error here
        super(Str);
        System.out.println("Sub " + Str);
    }
}
```